# How to select between edges?

Tags: modeling, edges, selection-tools, select

can i select the edges (red) between the blue edges on the screenshot somehow by one key? I've tried inner region selection, but it didn't help. Are there any script or addon that can help?
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You have to manually select them, but there is a quicker way to select columns of edges. Select one edge of one column, the upper left edge and then hold down `Ctrl` while selecting the bottom edge of that column. Then press and hold `Shift` to select another edge of the next column and then press and hold down `Ctrl` and select the bottom edge of that column. Repeat for every column of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
Check out the addon MaxViz Interactive Tools for Blender, there is an option to select "between edges"

Answer (score 3):

Not one click.. but without thinking too hard, my method would be something like:

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> Left-click, face-select the region by its corners
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> Hide the rest
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Edge-select by direction
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> Unhide

.. unfortunately the 'Unhide' operation has to be set **not** to select the revealed elements, but that only has to be done once. I wish the default was the other way.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I wish there could be a sctript for that...

Comment: Hi, @Eno, Thanks! It's a bit too specific for a tool, IMO?  One of the reasons I enjoy Blender is that it at least _tries_ to keep its tool-set minimal and complete, rather than drowning me in buttons, like, say, 3DS. (That's a personal preference.) :)